# Why is cordova picking up the wrong JDK version?

Tags: java, android, macos, cordova

On macOS, when running the terminal command

```
cordova build android
```

I get an error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/arnas/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/arnas/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected version: 15.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

although running `java -version` returns `java version "1.8.0_291"`

My bash_profile settings are:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command which java in order to understand the path of your java version 1.8 and then set JAVA_HOME with that path removing the bin/java.
That is:

```
which java    
/usr/bin/java1.8/bin/java
```

and then replace in your bash_profile your current 'export JAVA_HOME...' with

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java1.8
```

Comment: for me, which java returns "/usr/bin/java" so is that what I should put as JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, was actually setting JAVA_HOME manually in the bash_profile by running `nano ~/.bash_profile` and entering the line:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

I obtained the file path by finding the latest JDK version in the JavaVirtualMachines directory.